# Turn off validation in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do turn off validation in `Rails 3.2.3` in `seeds.rb`? I did this

```
u1 = User.create email: 'my@email.com', password: '123', validate: false
```

but it said `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: validate`. I know what it means. So how do I get rid of that error?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846314/ruby-on-rails-skipping-validate-on-create-statement-for-seeds

Comment: it's not a duplicate at all!

Comment: You use the `create` function within seeds and want to turn of the validations for that. In the linked post, the User wishes to skip the validation on creation of objects in his seed files. That is an identical goal. Furthermore: the first answer in the linked question matches your question beautifully.

Comment: why do I have to do all these complicated actions?

Comment: Because you try to act against the intentions of rails. The more you do so, the harder it gets to write code. The approach of @iltempo works as well.

Comment: I know that it works well that's why I'll use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do

```
u1 = User.new(email: 'my@email.com', password: '123').save(validate: false)
```