# ActiveRecord: Skip validation when saving multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know I can skip validations for an individual save, like this:

```
User.new(name: 'John').save(validate: false)
```

But how can I do that when saving multiple objects at once? Like this:

```
Category.create([
  { name: 'Apps' },
  { name: 'Songs' },
  { name: 'Movies' }
])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this gem: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

It works like this:

```
categories = [ 
  Category.new(name: 'Apps'),
  Category.new(name: 'Songs'),
  Category.new(name: 'Movies')
]

Category.import(categories, validate: false)
```

[It is also possible to use plain arrays instead of ActiveRecord objects.](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#examples)

I guess it generates pure SQL when *validate* is set to false so it can skip validations.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that with `create`. If you really must skip validations you can do something like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Apps' },
  { name: 'Songs' },
  { name: 'Movies' }
].each do |attributes|
  c = Category.new(attributes)
  s.save(validate: false)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this alternative. However I need to save some long data sets and this way would generate many SQL inserts. The [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem worked best for me because it generates a single insert.